# Breaking the record

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, no-computers

There is a record whose value is expressed by a natural number. (The value is strictly discrete, not only continuous and then rounded to a natural number.) However, after the record is once established, any other person to topple the previous record-holder will break it by at least 2. The value of the record can be expressed by both odd and even numbers.

For instance, if the current score is 505, the next record-holder's score may be 507, 508, 509, etc., but it may not be 506.

What record is this?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling;)

Comment: just want to check, this is a real record right?

Comment: Generally, any riddles on this site need to go through the sandbox (http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox)   If this has already, please mention so in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @AvikMohan. No they don't http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5372/19989. And this is not a riddle.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, yes this record does exist, but the solution is not strictly contingent upon its factuality.

Comment: @AvikMohan, oh, sorry. I didn't see that. If I happen to come up with anything else, I'll go there. :)

Comment: @Marius, according to the Stack definition, "[a] riddle gives indirect clues about an unnamed object or concept to be identified. It is often presented in the form of a poem." Doesn't that fit?

Comment: @Widdershins. I don't know what to say. This does not look like a riddle to me. It's not a poem, that's for sure. But this is not a requirement. Also it does not provide clues towards something. But I may be wrong on this one. But one think is certain. For now you don't need to go through the sandbox with any riddles.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

My shot:

> The record for the most records a person has broken.

In order to break that record:

> you need to break another record and you will break this one also.  So +2

Example:

> A person has broken 505 records and that's the biggest number of records.
>  In order to break that record, you need to break at least 506 records. But if you do, you instantly have at least 507 broken records, because you broke the record for the most records a person has broken.

Comment: Say, if you get 506, and that bumps you up to 507, wouldn't that bump the old holder down to 504, since they don't hold that record anymore?

Comment: @fuandon. Yes, it does, but that still does not break my explanation. The previous record was 505 and the new record is 507. What's on second place it does not matter. Even if you have a +3 over second place you still broke the record by +2.

Comment: Yeah, true, the question does say 'at least two', sorry!

Comment: Congratulations. :)

Comment: I fear this is actually quite complicated. If Person A has 500 normal records, then 1 more for most records, he'd have 501. If Person B gets to 500 records, does he then share the "most records" record? If so, they'd both have 501 (or 500 if you count it that way). Person B then breaks another normal record would have his 501st and move ahead, so he'd now have 502 records and Person A, with only 500 normal records and no share of the most-records record would drop to 500.  But the *record number* itself has only increased by 1, from 501 to 502.

Comment: So the difference between 1st and 2nd will always be >= 2, but I think the record itself can increment by 1 (which is counter to the way the question's stated right now).

Comment: @DanRussell,

The way I perceive it, the answer to your question "If Person B gets to 500 records, does he then share the "most records" record?" is "no." Person B has to break 502 normal records to get the "most broken records" record (because the previous holder had 501 records, right). Thus, Person B has 503 records now, and that is 2 more than the previous record.

Comment: Okay, then there's an important distinction between *holding* records and *breaking* records, and this answer is not quite right.

Comment: Well, yeah, I guess it could have been worded better.

Comment: Marius: hope you don't mind the edit.  If we're talking about just how many records a person *holds*, then that number can go down which makes the puzzle moot, because then the record record holder's total could drop if a different one of his records were broken.

Comment: @DanRussell. Thanks for the edit. It makes it fully politically correct now

Comment: @DanRussell You can't just *brake the record of number of broken records*. This can only be done if you have broken another record. So, if from 500 it gets to 501 but not 502, it seems it got from 499 to 500 to 501.

Comment: This record is currently held by Ashrita Furman of the USA, who is interviewed here: https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2015/sep/11/guinness-world-record (yes, I googled it).

Answer (score 6):

It could be:

> The record beating record :). Each time a record is beaten the record beating record increments twice (because it was itself beaten too).

Answer (score 6):

One possible answer is

> The largest prime number found / calculated / verified

It is a valid category of records that is well maintained and looked after. It is a strictly discrete number that technically can be both odd and even numbers, however, after it's been established, both the current and new records will always be odd and thus the difference will be at least 2.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> Biggest Largemouth Bass

To beat the previous world record, we need atleast 2 more ounces than previous.

Comment: Would that apply to other fish records as well? and it doesn't have an explanation that regards all the tags

Comment: I added information about the value's non-continuousness. Even if we need at least 2 ounces more, 2.5 will do the job, but the value of the record I was describing is expressed in natural numbers only.